# How to deal with an em dash in a filename

Tags: windows, batch-file

On a PC with Windows 7, I'm using a simple batch script to rename some Excel files, pre-pending their parent folder name:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /AD') do (
    cd "%%i"
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /b *.xl*') do ren "%%~j" "%%i_%%~j"
    cd..
)
```

I noticed that some files generated an error, "System cannot find the specified file." These files all had an em dash (—) in the filename. After I changed the em dash to a regular hyphen (-), using Windows Explorer, the script worked fine on these files.

How can I help script the rename of these files?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the batch variables: from the command line this works fine:

```
for %i in (*) do ren "%~i" "test_%~i"
```

but, as can be seen from:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /b /a-d') do @echo ren "%~i" "test2_%~i"
```

`dir /b` is changing the em dash to a hyphen, and so the `ren` command clearly won't find the file to change.

For your examples you should find:

```
for /d %%i in (*) do (
```

and

```
for %%j in (*.xl*) do ...
```

should work fine.

If you need the `dir /b` for other reasons, I don't see a solution right now.

<sub>(I had a convoluted attempt exchanging all hyphens for question marks, using the "Environment variable substitution" and "delayed environment variable expansion" as described in `SET /?` and `CMD /?`, allowing any character to match, and then again use `ren` pattern matching to ignore the problem.</sub>

<sub>I.e.</sub>

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
 Set K=%%I
 ren "!K:-=?!" "test2_!K:-=?!"
)
```

<sub>but `ren * x*` *replaces* the start of the files with `x`, so the above replaces the hyphens with the content at that location before `test_` was inserted.</sub>

<sub>So the best this approach can do is convert the em dashes to hyphens with:</sub>

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d') do (
 Set K=%%I
 ren "!K:-=?!" "test2_!K!"
)
```

<sub>)</sub>

And confirming it is the output of `dir /b` that is the problem: on the command line:

```
dir /b *—* > test.txt
```

where that `—` is an em dash, will only list the files with em dashes, but, in the output file, e.g. `Notepad test.txt`, you'll only find hyphens, and no em dashes.

BTW I've done all this testing on Windows 8.1 which `VER` displays as `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]`.

<sub>(As I mention above I did have `ren * x*` in this answer, but that *replaces* the first character with `x` rather than insert it, which I always thought `ren` did!)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Mark. Using `for %%j in (*.xl*) do` works fairly well but there's another problem now, though -  from looking at the filenames being "echoed" during the renaming process, it looks like after one file gets renamed it is dynamically added to the list (happens only with the first file out of three in my test), resulting in that file being renamed twice, e.g., "folderName_folderName_originalFilename." Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: I figured out a trick - make a temporary folder to move the file into after renaming, then move the files back and delete the temporary directory.