# cmd converts em-dash to hyphen on pasting. Any workaround?

Tags: cmd, special-characters

I want to be able to paste file paths into cmd with em dashes (—, alt 0151) in them.

cmd converts them to ones where the em dashes have been replaced by a hyphen.

**Manual input:**

1. (Keyboard) `D:\—\image.png`
2. (cmd) `D:\—\image.png`

Entering this would open the file as expected.

**Pasted input:**

1. (Clipboard) `D:\—\image.png`
2. (cmd) `D:\-\image.png`

Entering this would give me an error because a directory named hyphen doesn't exist.

This is baffling because the file system supports paths to have such a character - I can access this file if I type the path manually, and programs can open it just fine.

Why convert a character that is supported? If it wasn't supported when the conversion was added, why not remove the conversion when the support was added?

More importantly, how can I work around this while keeping the em dashes? I have programs that depend on such paths and it'd be inconvenient to change them in all of them.

---

**Similar to:**

[How to deal with an em dash in a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677677/how-to-deal-with-an-em-dash-in-a-filename)

[Using “En Dash” in an input file to a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970935/using-en-dash-in-an-input-file-to-a-batch-file)

[Rename Files having EmDash using a Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693969/rename-files-having-emdash-using-a-batch-file)

Changing the code page made no difference.

Comment: Well, seems such a character is not fully supported… `cmd` doesn't know anything about UTF-8, for instance, which is the commonly used text encoding nowadays; it somehow supports UTF-16, but it's always a mess with codepages and so on. That's why I generally avoid such characters in file paths/names and stick to the ASCII character set…

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to create an AutoHotKey script to parse the path being pasted and to send alt 0151 whenever it encounters an em dash.

It could be faster, but it works - which is miles better than receiving an error.

```
#SingleInstance, force

numpad7::
tooltip, exited!
Clipboard := stored
sleep, 300
exitapp

#IfWinActive ahk_exe cmd.exe
$^v::
cliptext := clipboard
stored := ClipboardAll
StringGetPos, garbage, cliptext, —
garbage =
if !ErrorLevel {
  Loop, Parse, cliptext 
  {
      char = %A_LoopField%
      If (char == "—") {
        clipboard := sentence
        sendinput, ^v
        SendInput {alt down}{numpad0}{numpad1}{numpad5}{numpad1}{alt up}
        sentence := ""
      } else if (char == "") {
        char := " "
        gosub define_sentence
      } else {
        gosub define_sentence
      }
    }
    ; send sentence when EOL
    gosub define_sentence
    Clipboard := sentence := SubStr(sentence, 1, -1)
    sendinput, ^v
    sleep 200
    Clipboard := stored
    stored =
    sentence =
  return
} else {
  sendinput, ^v
} 
return

define_sentence:
  sentence := sentence . char
  tool := "s= " . sentence . "`n" . "c= " . char
  tooltip, %tool%
  return
```

On another note, the highlight.js for autohotkey doesn't seem to work which is great.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off this [V2 behavior](https://superuser.com/a/954426/1689619) by disabling `FilterOnPaste` via `reg add HKCU\Console -v FilterOnPaste -d 0 -t REG_DWORD -f` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121001), a sing out may be required) or turning off all V2 features altogether via `reg add HKCU\Console -v ForceV2 -d 0 -t REG_DWORD -f`. You can always return values to their defaults via `reg add HKCU\Console -v FilterOnPaste -d 1 -t REG_DWORD -f` and `reg add HKCU\Console -v ForceV2 -d 1 -t REG_DWORD -f` respectfully.